# Hет подключения к бд mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Мне скинули папку с сайтом wpress. При попытке запустить его на локальном сервере выбивает ошибку подключения к БД. При попытке подключиться к бд через phpmyadmin(логин и пароль есть) - выбивает ошибку. В файле wp-config.php указано:

Имя сервера MySQL

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

Cвязка логин пароль тоже указана верно. В чем может быть проблема и как ее фиксить?

Comment: при попытке подключиться к бд через phpmyadmin ошибка:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Покажите код, что вы вписали, я вижу только ошибку связанную с паролем, который не нужно вводить, потому-что по умолчанию с именем root, пароль не требуется.

Comment: вот код подключения из wp-config `define('DB_NAME', 'anyreal_prod');

/** Имя пользователя MySQL */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** Пароль к базе данных MySQL */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'LKJhol0(i0j89h8ijl');

/** Имя сервера MySQL */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

/** Кодировка базы данных для создания таблиц. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** Схема сопоставления. Не меняйте, если не уверены. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');`

Comment: Сотрите пароль. И укажите ваше окружение, что за локальный сервер используете?

Comment: использую openserver

Comment: @MoloF пароль из кода стёр, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Папка с сайтом не содержит в себе БД. Настройки же БД указывают на некую базу данных, расположенную на том же сервер что и сам сайт. Вам необходимо поднять у себя MySQL (если он еще не запущен), создать в нем новую базу данных, настройки на которую и прописать в настройках вордпресса. При этом надо на том сервере где был сайт до этого, выполнить бекап нужной базы данных и развернуть этот бекап в БД созданную на вашем MySQL

Comment: @Mike а можно ли к той БД подключиться удаленно, не скачивая её? Что для этого нужно?

Comment: Так вы определитесь что вы хотите, локально войти в БД или же удаленно. Ваша текущая ошибка заключалась в пароле. А для решение проблемы с подключением к удаленной БД, нужно указать соответствующие данные. Их можно получить у хостинга

Comment: Для этого удаленную БД надо настроить на доступ снаружи, т.е. как минимум в ее конфигурации должен отсутствовать параметр bind_address=127.0.0.1 (по умолчанию присутствует), разрешить в фаерволе порт MySQL для подключений снаружи (если закрыт), лучше только для своей машины, а не для всего мира. Создать в MySQL отдельного пользователя, с доступом снаружи и имеющего доступ к требуемой БД (под root снаружи подключиться скорее всего нельзя). После чего в настройках вордпресса указать адрес сервера на котором MySQL и нужного пользователя с паролем

Comment: @MoloF мне нужно просто зайти на сайт и переписать js код и, соответственно, проверить как он работает. Но при попытке зайти на сайт с локального сервера выбивает ошибку Error establishing a database connection.  По сути мне и работа с бд не нужна. Другие юзеры же как то заходят спокойно на сайт, их пропускает.

Comment: Вы путаете предлоги. Пользователи заходят не С сервера, а НА сервер. И когда вы переносите сервер к себе, переносить надо целиком, включая БД.

Comment: У вас 3 варианта: 1. отлаживаться прямо на оригинальном сервере (не рекомендуется) 2. Установить у себя MySQL с копией БД, т.е. собрать полноценный отладочный стенд. 3. Открыть доступ на удаленной БД и подключаться к ней. И самым простым я бы назвал 2й пункт

Comment: @Mile спасибо, буду пробовать!